# The dashboard unhide under the opened windows

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, compiz

Mint 17.3, dashboard MATE 1.12.2, mintMenu 5.6.6, compiz

The dashboard (set as 'Automatically hidden') when activated by mouse hovering, opens **under** the opened windows: I do not find an option for that behaviour.

This behaviour in 1 system only, is it related to the video card  ?

How to get the dashboard unhide always **over** the opened windows ?

Comment: Update 07/082017: This morning, the behaviour has switched back to 'normal': Unhide **over** the windows.   No reason found  !